# SharePoint 2010 CQWP show results in batches

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, cqwp

I'm trying to create a "Relevant Articles" area on my SharePoint website, and I am using the CQWP (Content Query Web Part) to tailor the results to the metadata we've created for each page. So far so good.

Because the CQWP has an item limit and our web pages have limited space, we'd ideally like to have the results shown in batches of 5 at a time. The user should be able to click in the web part to scroll through additional articles (1 - 5 ; 6 - 10 ; etc).

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In the presentation option of your CQWP, put the item limit as 100 or 200.
And then use a bit of jquery to paginate these into groups of 5 or 6.